# Tensorflow case function does not work when pred_fn_pairs is built from for loop

Tags: python, tensorflow, case

I am having a weird issue here.

I am simply trying to apply a mapping on tensor values according some intervals.
For example, let's map tensor's values that are in the interval [0, 10] to 1, in the interval [10, 20] to 2, in the interval [20, 30] to 3 and others to 0.

If i build this mapping thanks to a list and iterates over it "by hand" it works fine.

```
def build_mult_mapping(l):
    return lambda x: tf.case({
                              tf.math.logical_and(tf.greater(x, tf.constant(l[0][0][0])), tf.less(x, tf.constant(l[0][0][1]))): lambda: tf.constant(l[0][1]),
                              tf.math.logical_and(tf.greater(x, tf.constant(l[1][0][0])), tf.less(x, tf.constant(l[1][0][1]))): lambda: tf.constant(l[1][1]),
                              tf.math.logical_and(tf.greater(x, tf.constant(l[2][0][0])), tf.less(x, tf.constant(l[2][0][1]))): lambda: tf.constant(l[2][1])
                              },
                              default=lambda: tf.constant(l[3]), exclusive=True)
```

It is ugly, but if i apply this `build_mult_mapping` version it works fine.

```
def f(x):
    mult_mapping = build_mult_mapping([((0, 10), 1), ((10, 20), 2), ((20, 30), 3), 0])
    return tf.map_fn(mult_mapping, x)

x = tf.constant([5, 15, 25, 35])
sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(f(x))
```

If i run this block i get: `array([1, 2, 3, 0], dtype=int32)` which is the expected output.

Now if i try to iterate over the `build_mult_mapping` argument `y` with a for loop, i get a weird behavior. Here is the new implementation

```
def build_mult_mapping(l):
    return lambda x: tf.case({tf.math.logical_and(tf.greater(x, tf.constant(i[0][0])), tf.less(x, tf.constant(i[0][1]))): lambda: tf.constant(i[1])
                              for i in l[:-1]
                             },
                             default=lambda: tf.constant(l[-1]), exclusive=True)
```

If i run the same block as before i get the following output `array([3, 3, 3, 0], dtype=int32)` whereas i am expecting to have the same as before.

Any ideas on what is happening ?